# Find which key triggered DOM "keydown" event (using JavaFX WebEngine)?

Tags: java, javafx-webengine

When the WebEngine finishes loading the page, it adds a "keydown" listener to a text input element.
How can I retrieve which key was pressed from within the listener?

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
        .addListener((ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, 
                State newState) -> {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                        Element ele = doc.getElementById("someInputField");

                        ((EventTarget) ele).addEventListener("keydown", (event) -> {
                        //if triggering key is 'ENTER'
                            doSomeMethod();
                    }, false);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a simple Java wrapper around the JavaScript engine, so it's a good bet it's in `event` as `event.key` and/or `event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is a `com.sun.webkit.dom.KeyboardEventImpl`, so you can get the Key with `getKeyCode()` or `getCharCode()`. Don't forget the metakeys like shift, ctrl....  (getAltKey(), getCtrlKey(), getShiftKey(), getMetaKey()).

The fastest way to get a type is reflection. But sometimes the debugger don't want to tell you the type. Then you can use an old trick `println`.

```
((EventTarget) ele).addEventListener("keydown", (event) -> {
    //if triggering key is 'ENTER'
    System.out.println(event.toString());
    if ("Enter".contentEquals(((com.sun.webkit.dom.KeyboardEventImpl) event).getKeyIdentifier())) {
        System.out.println("keydown on Enter");
    }
}, false);
```

Another way to solve the debugging problems with java lambdas is, not to use them.

```
 ((EventTarget) ele).addEventListener("keydown", new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(((com.sun.webkit.dom.KeyboardEventImpl) evt).getKeyCode()));
        com.sun.webkit.dom.KeyboardEventImpl event = (com.sun.webkit.dom.KeyboardEventImpl) evt;
        System.out.println(event.getKeyIdentifier());
    }
}, false);
```

I think, that I'm old....